# Problem creating Glossaries

Tags: glossaries, textcase

since some days I try to fix a problem using the glossaries package. However, until now, I can't solve it...
Even a minimal example is already throwing an error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

This will be the log result:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6400) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.10.17)  18 OCT 2017 08:35 entering extended mode
**"D:/Dis_Unterlagen/Eigene Paper/test/LaTeX1.tex" ("D:/Dis_Unterlagen/Eigene Paper/test/LaTeX1.tex" LaTeX2e <2017-04-15> Babel <3.14> and hyphenation patterns for 77 language(s) loaded. ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls" Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo" File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option) ) \c@part=\count79 \c@section=\count80 \c@subsection=\count81 \c@subsubsection=\count82 \c@paragraph=\count83 \c@subparagraph=\count84 \c@figure=\count85 \c@table=\count86 \abovecaptionskip=\skip41 \belowcaptionskip=\skip42 \bibindent=\dimen102 ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
2.9\tex\latex\glossaries\base\mfirstuc.sty" Package: mfirstuc 2011/04/02 v1.05 (NLCT) \@glsmfirst=\toks14 \@glsmrest=\toks15 ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
2.9\tex\latex\glossaries\base\glossaries.sty" Package: glossaries 2017/09/20 v4.33 (NLCT)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty" Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC) ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xkeyval\xkeyval.sty" Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkeyval.tex" ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkvutils.tex" \XKV@toks=\toks16 \XKV@tempa@toks=\toks17

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\keyval.tex")) \XKV@depth=\count87 File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA) )) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
2.9\tex\latex\textcase\textcase.sty" Package: textcase 2004/10/07 v0.07 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC) )

! LaTeX Error: \mfirstucMakeUppercase undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type  H <return>  for immediate help.  ...                                    

                                                   l.47 \renewcommand*{\mfirstucMakeUppercase}
                                           {\MakeTextUppercase}% Try typing  <return>  to proceed. If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xfor\xfor.sty" Package: xfor 2009/02/05 v1.05 (NLCT) ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
2.9\tex\latex\datatool\datatool-base.sty" Package: datatool-base 2016/07/28 v2.27 (NLCT)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty" Package: etoolbox 2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW) \etb@tempcnta=\count88 ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
2.9\tex\latex\ams\math\amsmath.sty" Package: amsmath 2000/07/18 v2.13 AMS math features \@mathmargin=\skip43

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option. ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ams\math\amstext.sty" Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ams\math\amsgen.sty" File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 \@emptytoks=\toks18 \ex@=\dimen103 )) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ams\math\amsbsy.sty" Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d \pmbraise@=\dimen104 ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ams\math\amsopn.sty" Package: amsopn 1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names ) \inf@bad=\count89 LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 211. \uproot@=\count90 \leftroot@=\count91 LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line
307. \classnum@=\count92 \DOTSCASE@=\count93 LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 379. LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line
382. LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 467. \Mathstrutbox@=\box26 \strutbox@=\box27 \big@size=\dimen105 LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 567. LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 568. \macc@depth=\count94 \c@MaxMatrixCols=\count95 \dotsspace@=\muskip10 \c@parentequation=\count96 \dspbrk@lvl=\count97 \tag@help=\toks19 \row@=\count98 \column@=\count99 \maxfields@=\count100 \andhelp@=\toks20 \eqnshift@=\dimen106 \alignsep@=\dimen107 \tagshift@=\dimen108 \tagwidth@=\dimen109 \totwidth@=\dimen110 \lineht@=\dimen111 \@envbody=\toks21 \multlinegap=\skip44 \multlinetaggap=\skip45 \mathdisplay@stack=\toks22 LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2666. LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2667. ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
2.9\tex\latex\substr\substr.sty" Package: substr 2009/10/20 v1.2 Handle substrings \c@su@anzahl=\count101 ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\datatool\datatool-fp.sty" Package: datatool-fp 2016/07/28 v2.27 (NLCT)

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp.sty" Package: fp 1995/04/02

`Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\defpattern.sty" Package: defpattern 1994/10/12 \actioncount=\count102 ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-basic.sty" Package: fp-basic 1996/05/13 \FP@xs=\count103 \FP@xia=\count104 \FP@xib=\count105 \FP@xfa=\count106 \FP@xfb=\count107 \FP@rega=\count108 \FP@regb=\count109 \FP@regs=\count110 \FP@times=\count111 ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-addons.sty" Package: fp-addons 1995/03/15 ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-snap.sty" Package: fp-snap 1995/04/05 ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-exp.sty" Package: fp-exp 1995/04/03 ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-trigo.sty" Package: fp-trigo 1995/04/14 ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-pas.sty" Package: fp-pas 1994/08/29 ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-random.sty" Package: fp-random 1995/02/23 \FPseed=\count112 ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-eqn.sty" Package: fp-eqn 1995/04/03 ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-upn.sty" Package: fp-upn 1996/10/21 ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
2.9\tex\latex\fp\fp-eval.sty" Package: fp-eval 1995/04/03 ))) \@dtl@toks=\toks23 \@dtl@tmpcount=\count113 \dtl@tmplength=\skip46 \dtl@sortresult=\count114 \@dtl@numgrpsepcount=\count115 \@dtl@datatype=\count116 \dtl@codeA=\count117 \dtl@codeB=\count118 \@dtl@foreach@level=\count119 ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
2.9\tex\latex\glossaries\base\glossaries-compat ible-307.sty" Package: glossaries-compatible-307 2017/09/20 v4.33 (NLCT) ) \gls@level=\count120 \@gls@tmpb=\toks24 \gls@tmplen=\skip47 \glskeylisttok=\toks25 \glslabeltok=\toks26 \glsshorttok=\toks27 \glslongtok=\toks28

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
2.9\tex\latex\glossaries\styles\glossary-hypern av.sty" Package: glossary-hypernav 2017/09/20 v4.33 (NLCT) ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\glossaries\styles\glossary-list.s ty" Package: glossary-list 2017/09/20 v4.33 (NLCT) \glslistdottedwidth=\skip48 ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
2.9\tex\latex\glossaries\styles\glossary-long.s ty" Package: glossary-long 2017/09/20 v4.33 (NLCT)  ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
2.9\tex\latex\tools\longtable.sty" Package: longtable 2014/10/28 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC) \LTleft=\skip49 \LTright=\skip50 \LTpre=\skip51 \LTpost=\skip52 \LTchunksize=\count121 \LTcapwidth=\dimen112 \LT@head=\box28 \LT@firsthead=\box29 \LT@foot=\box30 \LT@lastfoot=\box31 \LT@cols=\count122 \LT@rows=\count123 \c@LT@tables=\count124 \c@LT@chunks=\count125 \LT@p@ftn=\toks29 ) \glsdescwidth=\skip53 \glspagelistwidth=\skip54 ) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
2.9\tex\latex\glossaries\styles\glossary-super. sty" Package: glossary-super 2017/09/20 v4.33 (NLCT)  ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\supertabular\supertabular.sty" Package: supertabular 2004/02/20 v4.1e the supertabular environment \c@tracingst=\count126 \ST@wd=\dimen113 \ST@rightskip=\skip55 \ST@leftskip=\skip56 \ST@parfillskip=\skip57 \ST@pageleft=\dimen114 \ST@headht=\dimen115 \ST@tailht=\dimen116 \ST@pagesofar=\dimen117 \ST@pboxht=\dimen118 \ST@lineht=\dimen119 \ST@stretchht=\dimen120 \ST@prevht=\dimen121 \ST@toadd=\dimen122 \ST@dimen=\dimen123 \ST@pbox=\box32 )) ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX
2.9\tex\latex\glossaries\styles\glossary-tree.s ty" Package: glossary-tree 2017/09/20 v4.33 (NLCT) \glstreeindent=\skip58 )) (LaTeX1.aux) \openout1 = `LaTeX1.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line
86. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 86. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 86. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 86. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 86. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 86. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 86. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 86. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 86. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 86. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 86. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 86.  (LaTeX1.aux) )  Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:  4614 strings out of 493308  67217 string characters out of 3135826  178722 words of memory out of 3000000  8119 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000  3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000  1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191  45i,1n,26p,2030b,36s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

No pages of output. PDF statistics:  0 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)  0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)  1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

If someone has an idea, which I can still try, I would be very grateful!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try deleting the auxiliary files and re-compile (your MWE gives no error to me).

Comment: Also, it seems your version of the `mfirstuc` package is quite old, you should try to update it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments. It helped a lot.

I've already updated the mfirstuc packege. However, due to the comments, I noticed, that still an old version is used. So I have then determined that the glossaries package has its own mfristuc.sty file (within the glossaries folder structure). Replacing this with the updated version from the mfirstuc package solves the problem!

Comment: If `glossaries` has `mfirstuc.sty` with it then your version of `glossaries` also needs updating. (`mfirstuc` v2.0 was split off from `glossaries` in `glossaries` version 4.18.)